# Installing pl-debugger in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

Facing issues while installing pl-debugger in Ubuntu 22.04 and following installation from this [link](https://gist.github.com/eneldoserrata/6633963a1dbb63001b2e3c4a6a5e9bba).

I tried to install pl-debugger in Ubuntu 22.04 but facing an error shown below:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4cIN.png):

```bash
■ vinay@Vinay-Kumar-Tcarejo.: 
$ git clone git://git.postgresql.org/git/pldebugger.git 
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'pldebugger': Permission denied  
$ sudo git clone git://git.postgresql.org/git/pldebugger.git Cloning into 'pldebugger'... 
fatal: remote error: access denied or repository not exported: /git/pldebugger.git
```

If anyone had solved it previously, need help.

Answer (score 1):

The error message you have encountered tells us that there might be an issue with accessing or exporting the repository.

You should give the repository URL another look, check for its availability and verify the repository permissions. Also ensure that your package sources or repositories are up to date.

Answer (score 1):

1)Copy the Apache Age directory to the "contrib/" directory within the PostgreSQL source tree. This directory is typically located in the PostgreSQL installation directory.

2)Open a command prompt or terminal and navigate to the PostgreSQL source tree.

3)Run the following commands in order:

```
make - This command compiles the Apache Age extension.
make install - This command installs the Apache Age extension.
```

Locate the "postgresql.conf" file. This file contains configuration settings for PostgreSQL.

4)Open the "postgresql.conf" file in a text editor.

5)Find the line that contains the "shared_preload_libraries" setting.

6)Modify the "shared_preload_libraries" line to include the Apache Age library. For example, you would change it to:

```
shared_preload_libraries = '$libdir/plugin_debugger'
```

7)Save the changes to the "postgresql.conf" file.

8)Restart the PostgreSQL server to apply the new configuration.

9)Open the psql terminal or any PostgreSQL client of your choice.

10)Run the following command within the psql terminal:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pldbgapi;
```

This command installs the Apache Age extension and makes it available for use.

Answer (score 0):

**You can download it from there:**
https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/pldebugger

In order to access the repository you have mentioned, you need to be a **member** of the PostgreSQL community and have the **appropriate permissions**

Answer (score 0):

pl-debugger can be downloaded from this [like](https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/pldebugger).

**Installation Process**

- Copy the directory to contrib/ in PostgreSQL source tree.
- Run `make; make install`
- In the postgresql.conf file, modify the line with shared_preload_libraries

  shared_preload_libraries = '$libdir/plugin_debugger'
- Restart the server
- Run `CREATE EXTENSION pldbgapi;` in the psql terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You are cloning repo via ssh. You have to have SSH-keys associated with your account.

First [generate the SSH-Keys](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)

and then [add ssh keys](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account) to your Github account.

After cloning you will be able to clone the repository and follow the steps as per pldebugger [documentation - github - repo](https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/pldebugger),

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use HTTPS URL to clone your repository:

```
git clone https://git.postgresql.org/git/pldebugger.git
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue seems to be related to permissions because you do not have the necessary permissions to access the repository or create a directory for the repo.
One solution could be to clone the git repository to the home directory where it won't give issues related to permissions.
This can be done using the following command:

```
git clone git://git.postgresql.org/git/pldebugger.git ~/pldebugger
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't have proper authentication for your git account which is failing the clone command. Follow this [link](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account) for authentication with keys.